# .htaccess rules for pushstate support

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess, silex, pushstate

I started an app based on Angular.js and Silex for the server side.

I would use real URL (without hash) but it's not working.

I have activate pushstate on angular with the following line :

```
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

but I don't know how to configure server. Actually when I try to access to localhost/test angular did nothing but silex said : *No route found for "GET /test" ..

my htaccess is like it :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
```

Structure of my project is Like it

|--app/
|----app.php
|----controllers/
|-------MainController.php
|--web/
|----index.php
|----js/
|---------app.js
...

Thanks you for your help

edit :

route declaration :

```
config(['$routeProvider, $locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider.when('/test',{
    templateUrl : '/cuisine',
    controller  : 'CookController'
});
```

}

Comment: Please show your route definition for `/test`.

Comment: added in my question

Answer (score 0):

I am using this on my site, and its working , please give it try. Otherwise i suggest you turn on mod_rewrite logging in apache and look to logs

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with *RewriteBase*. The rewrite base is based on URI folder and you're requesting */test* not ***/web***/test, so your rewrite base should be /

I'm just guessing but I think your document root is */path/to/your/project/web* (it should be this, only the web directory is meant to be public!) so your .htaccess shouldn't have the RewriteBase on your case.

Comment: Hum, my index.php is in /web so if i haven't the RewriteBase I have an error when i do localhost/test..  If i do localhost/#test , my route work and url become localhost/test in my addressbar but when i reload the page i've the silex error : No route found for "GET /shopListing"...

Comment: Can you post your route declaration in Silex?